# Center textview: why don't work?

Tags: android, xml

I have a `ListView` and a `TextView`. When there is a condition the `TextView` is visible else no.
The XML code is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="No controls"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `TextView` is centered only in horizontal, why not in vertical? If I change the `layout_height` of `listview` in `match_parent` is centered also in vertical but I don't want a `match_parent` to layout height of `listview`. There are other solutions?

Comment: Can you show us in screen shots?

Comment: Of course: http://i59.tinypic.com/nex06p.png

Comment: Are you setting layout params programmatically?

Comment: when the list view is empty then the textview will be shown...m i right..?

Answer (score 0):

use this.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="No controls" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```